# Cannot read property 'dia' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jointjs

I am new to jointjs and having a hard time to import jointjs in my React project. The error I get is 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dia' of undefined. I am using  this versions for my project jointjs: 3.0.4,  lodash:  4.17.14, and jquery: 3.4.1;

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
import  _ from "lodash";
import './App.css';
import joint from "jointjs";


class App extends React.Component{  

  constructor(){
    super()

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.InitializeGraph();
  }

InitializeGraph(){

  var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
  new joint.dia.Paper({ el: $('#paper-html-elements'), width: 650, height: 400, gridSize: 1, model: 
  graph });

 }


  render(){
    return(
    <div>
   <div id='paper-html-elements'> </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try to check `joint `. maybe using console.log(). it should be an object

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation there is not default import anymore.

You need to do this

```
import * as joint from 'jointjs'
```

Or you can import `dia` itself by -

```
import { dia } from 'jointjs/src/core.mjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as well:

```
import * as joint from "jointjs/index";
```